# how can i Combining Multiple different DMGs for my application

Tags: macos, qt, join, dmg

I am new to iOS/OS X. I have written kernel code, Qt app and Front End application for my application for OS X & tested it, works fine.

Problems facing :

I have to make a single distributable .dmg, which will install all three codes{kernel code, Qt app & Front end application } in separate directories with single double click.

How can i make this work ?

Methods Tried :

1) I made separate .dmg and added to a folder and again created another .dmg of folder .(But it require again to double click to install all three code parts)

2) I tried to generate .dmg with command line macdeployqt, Disk Utility, IDMG , DropDMG (It help in also adding licenses).

2a) DropDMG have the option of joining and then convert Image /Archiver its not working, After i joined the first file (file.001) ,it shows message "Use Convert ..to join ".dmgpart"files. when i try for convert Image /Archiver option, it doesn't detect files (.dmgpart)

Note : I am using DropDMG trail version and i renamed all three files as file.001 , file.002.dmgpart and file.003.dmgpart (as per user guild )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `.dmg` is a [disk image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Disk_Image), not an installer; you need to create an Installer Package instead.

**PRODUCTBUILD**

> productbuild -- Build a product archive for the OS X Installer or the Mac App Store

A product archive is a flat file with a `.pkg` extension.  productbuild creates a deployable product archive, archive,
     chive, which can be used with the OS X Installer.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/productbuild.1.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/1/productbuild

**PKGBUILD**

> pkgbuild -- Build an OS X Installer component package from on-disk
>   files

A `component package` contains payload to be installed by the OS X Installer. Although a component
     package can be installed on its own, it is typically incorporated into a product archive, along with a
     `distribution` and localized resources, using [productbuild](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/productbuild.1.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/1/productbuild)(1).

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/pkgbuild.1.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/1/pkgbuild